# How do I import a Google Module directly in AWS Lambda?

Tags: python, aws-lambda

I am trying to process an audio file from my S3 through a Lambda function which should call the google speech api to to speech-to-text with the file. However, it doesn't seem like Lambda has this module installed.

Is there a way to import the module externally/manually?

```
import json
import boto3
import array as arr
import botocore
from botocore.vendored import requests
import os
import urllib
from google.cloud import speech
from google.cloud.speech import enums
from google.cloud.speech import types

def lambda_handler(event, context):
    output = 'test'
    return output
```

Expected is that the import works, however the error output is the following:

```
"errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': No module 
   named 'google'",
```

Comment: What was the solution that you used?

Answer (score 2):

You have to add the google library to your deployment package. Depending on your deployment process, there's various ways how to go about it. The [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-python-how-to-create-deployment-package.html) is a good place to start learning about that.

BTW, instead of Google's speech-to-text you can use the one from AWS called [Transcribe](https://aws.amazon.com/transcribe/). You don't have to install any additional library to use that, `boto3` will do.

Comment: Thank you. There are internal reasons for using google speech, so we can't get around that. I tried a deploy through a virtualenv. However, now I get the following error:

`{
  "errorMessage": "Unable to import module 'lambda_function': cannot import name 'cygrpc' from 'grpc._cython' (/var/task/grpc/_cython/__init__.py)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.ImportModuleError"
}`

I already tried force reinstalling grpc again in the directory.

Comment: How are you creating the deployment package? The libraries have to be pip installed in a Lambda-compatible OS. The error indicates that they weren't. Have a look at AWS SAM and the sam build --use-container command. It will create a deployment package for you, the dependencies will be built in a Docker container that's equivalent to the Lambda one.

Answer (score 2):

Check the python version used for installing the dependencies and give the same runtime in aws Lambda. I used python 3.8 for installing and gave 3.7 in runtime and ran into this error.

Answer (score 0):

A better way would be to create a file called `requirements.txt` and add all the dependencies in there

```
google-cloud-speech==0.36.0
```

Comment: Thank you, however adding a `requirements.txt` does not seem to work.

Comment: specify the target `python3 -m pip install -t . -r requirements.txt`

Answer (score 0):

On my understanding, this problem could be solved by adding the required modules as a Layer in Lambda. Then it will be available to your script.

Also, that Layer could be re-used for other Lambdas in the future.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).